# Filter CSS according to used selectors

Tags: html, css, compare, summernote

I am implementing the Summernote Editor which rely on Bootstrap, but I usse my own custom stylesheet. This gives me 2 problems:

1. It breaks my design and the Bootstrap file is so long it is difficult to find the exact selectors causing the trouble.
2. It loads a 120kB file, when maybe just 20-30 is necessary (the part actually needed for the editor to render nice).

Does anyone know a tool (maybe online) to compare the actual used tags, classes etc. in the source code with the attached stylesheet pointing out what is in use?
Could also be helpful after a long developing proces, where you have made a lot of editing and you maybe ended up with a lot of un-used code.

Comment: A possible option to consider is [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) to identify/remove unused CSS. Tools like that require a build system such as Gulp or Grunt. It just one option, there are more like it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click and select Inspect Element while you are on your webpage on any browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [purifyCSS](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss), which would require grunt or alike.  There's this site https://unused-css.com/, which would require a URL of your site, it then would scan just a single page of that site.  There's also this tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssscanner/, which gives you list of used and unused selectors, but you need a machine running Windows to use.